# angular router-outlet doen't render anything

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I am a beginner in angular.I am following a lecture and doing hands-on.I write the following code following the instructor.But this doen't render anything.Please help

**app.module.ts :**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BsNavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent,
    CheckOutComponent,
    OrderSucessfulComponent,
    MyOrdersComponent,
    AdminProductsComponent,
    AdminOrdersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,

  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
export const appRoutes: Routes = [

  {path:'',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'products',component:ProductsComponent},
  {path:'shopping-cart',component:ShoppingCartComponent},
  {path:'check-out',component:CheckOutComponent},
  {path:'order-sucessful',component:OrderSucessfulComponent},
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'admin/products',component:AdminProductsComponent},
  {path:'admin/orders',component:AdminOrdersComponent}

  ]


  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<bs-navbar></bs-navbar>

<main role="main" class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</main>
```

Comment: what is `<main> ?`

Comment: I copied this from bootstrap default template

Comment: In your `imports` array, remove `RouterOutlet,` add `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);` and define your routes above the @ngModule decorator

Comment: @ploppy i did.that did not help

Answer (score 0):

In your imports please remove RouterOutlet and add RouterModule like this

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ]
```

Comment: I did and the result is same

Comment: Can you please post your code in stackblitz so that I can take a look into it whats wrong

Comment: I it possible to copy and paste my entire project in stackblitz ?

Comment: I guess there was problem with your copy pasting there are two src folders please correct it and upload it again and NgModule doesn't look like it is in the post

Comment: Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "main". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags (" <router-outlet></router-outlet>